# Navigation in child view

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm creating navigation between screens in my react-native application, but i have a problem, i have a parent view and inside it rendered a child view whenever i try to pass the navigation as a prop for the child view it gives me an error, can anyone please tell me how am i supposed to pass it? here is what I tried to do:

> App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Parent from './components/Parent';
import {
  createStackNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation';

const App = createStackNavigator({
  Parent: { screen: Parent },
});
```

> Parent component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import Child from './Child';


 class Parent extends Component {

   render() {
     return (
       <Text>Parent Component</Text>
       <Child />
     );

 export default Parent;
```

> Child component:

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
 class Child extends Component {
   render() {
     const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
     return(
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {props.navigation.navigate('Parent')}}>
      );   
 export default Child;
```

and this is the error:

> undefined is not an object evaluating _this.props.navigation

Comment: Can you add your parent and child component relevant code as well? For example how are you passing the props.

Comment: @PritishVaidya updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the navigation props explicitly to the `<Child/>` component as

### Parent

```
 <Child navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
```

### Child

```
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
  return(
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {navigate('Parent')}} />
);
```

and in the **Parent** wrap your JSX in a `<View/>`

```
<View>
  <Text>Parent Component</Text>
  <Child navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
</View>
```

Comment: Is the App.js exported and rendered appropriately? The rest of the code is correct, Check the `TouchableOpacity` render method to mine. Closing tag is missing